# How to install app in playstore without Google playstore in android emulator

Tags: google-play-store, android-emulator, google-apps, android-sdk

I had installed AndroVM to use Android apps in computer. But when it comes to games like shadow fight even with OpenGL support enabled, AndroVM couldn't run many games such as Hill Climb racing, Gunship battle etc. Hence I tried Genymotion. When I installed Genymotion, it automatically detected AndroVM installed in Virtual Box. And I could only run Hill climb racing and rest of them didn't work. So I finally installed Android SDK and followed all instructions to add packages(Tools, extras and System Images). Even if I have installed Google play services and Google repository, I couldn't find Google playstore in the android emulator. Even [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11154222/google-play-on-android-4-0-emulator) post suggests how to install Google playstore in emulator,it also have discussions about piracy and legal issues(in comments) and the apk's (GoogleLoginService.apk , GoogleServicesFramework.apk , Phonesky.apk) are not official packages. Hence

1. Can any one suggest how can I install apps inside emulator without using Google playstore, and
2. Why can't I find playstore even after I install Google play services and repository.

[These](http://i1374.photobucket.com/albums/ag412/padmahas/AndroidSDK_zpse23faba0.png) are the packages I've installed. And I'm using Ubuntu 14.04

**Update**
If you cannot open the image. Here I've copied exact names of the packages.

```
Tools:

Name                              API   Rev      Status    
Android SDK tools                       23.0.5   installed    
Android SDK platform tools              21       installed
Android SDK build tools                 21.0.1   installed
Android SDK build tools                 20       installed

Android 5.0(API 21)

documentation for Android SDK     21    1        installed
SDK platform                      21    1        installed
Android TV ARM EABI v7a System    21    1        installed
image
ARM EABI v7a System image         21    1        installed
Sources for Android SDK           21    1        installed

Extras:

Android support Library                 21       installed
Google Play services                    20       installed
Google Repository                       12       installed
```

Comment: "These" is a link to an image that doesn't seem to load on my end. I'm running [Android-x86](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/android-x86) in VirtualBox on my Ubuntu machine, no issues with using Playstore, F-Droid, or Aptoide to install apps. Maybe you want to try that?

Comment: Hello @Izzy, What do you mean by "Android-x86"? Is it any kind of virtual box image like AndroVM? The link of "Andeoid-x86" took me to list of questions. And sorry the Image couldn't load for you. I'll update through text, but I need further help from you.

Comment: @GrIsHu In [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20438349/emulator-not-showing-file-browser-to-access-sdcard) link you have commented checkout my answer but you have neither posted any answer nor provided link. Even I want to access SD card (and it should be from inside emulator). Please give me link and I'll be happy if you can answer the above question too.

Comment: Yes, you can install it in VirtualBox like any Linux distro, as it's Android ported to the x86 platform (see the [Android-x86 homepage](http://www.android-x86.org/)). I've linked to the tag originally as we have already questions here explaining things around it, which I thought you might find more helpful.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you have only one emulator running, then you can install an apk file by using adb

```
adb -e install <apk file>
```

You get more options by

```
adb -h
```

Comment: Its showing `The program 'adb' is currently not installed. You can install it by typing:
sudo apt-get install android-tools-adb` But in the package I've listed, I've installed all the platform tools and build tools

Comment: Adb is located in <android-sdk>/platform-tools. You will surely find it there. To make life easier, set your environment variable ANDROID_HOME and add it to your path.